# Mongodb Aggregation pipeline: Is it possible to do $match based on two conditions?

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate

I am new to Mongodb, been working on an aggregation pipeline. Have this collection called students:-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62304f3a53b273b7a6ea0eca"), "name" : "Ankita", "subject" : "English", "marks" : 70 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62304f3a53b273b7a6ea0ecb"), "name" : "Ritwik", "subject" : "Maths", "marks" : 80 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6232c4b8c2f3cc1a0e9fa107"), "name" : "Mayank", "subject" : "Science", "marks" : 85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6232c4b8c2f3cc1a0e9fa108"), "name" : "Ankita", "subject" : "History", "marks" : 90 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6232c4b8c2f3cc1a0e9fa109"), "name" : "Ritwik", "subject" : "Economics",  "marks" : 75 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6232fa5fc2f3cc1a0e9fa10a"), "name" : "Mayank", "subject" : "Polity", "marks" : 60 }
```

Based on a given number, asOfMarks(lets say 65 here) and given includeNames( lets say ['Mayank','Ankita'] here), I want the result to be something like this:-

```
{ "name" : "Mayank", "marks" : 60, "subject" : "Polity" }
{ "name" : "Ankita", "marks" : 70, "subject" : "English" }
```

It should group by the includeNames provided, and If there exists a row with marks less than the asOfMarks, show rows with marks just less than the asOfMarks, ( like that in case of 'Mayank'). If not, show the row with the minimum marks(like in case of 'Ankita')

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try this query:

- Frist `$match` using `$in` to filter only by names in the array.
- Then use `$facet` to create "two ways". First one the values less than 65, and the other the nearest.
- To get the nearest, first `$match` by great than 65 to avoid duplicates and sort by `marks`, group by name and get only the `$first` element. As the documents are sorted, the first element will be the nearest to 65.
- With all data you want you can set at the top level of the document using the next stages:
- `$concatArrays` to get all values (from `less` and `near`) in a single array. Inside this stage I've used `$map` to get the values on the top, not into `result` from the `$group` and also `$filter` to avoid duplicates.
- So now `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and prepare the data to the next stage
- And `$replaceRoot` to create a new root structure document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": {
        "$in": [
          "Mayank",
          "Ankita"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "less": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "marks": {
              "$lte": 65
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "near": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "marks": {
              "$gt": 65
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "marks": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "result": {
              "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$less",
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$near",
                  "cond": {
                    "$not": {
                      "$in": [
                        "$$this.result.name",
                        "$less.name"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": "$$this.result"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$result"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-zSiHczlbZN)